# How to dynamically create a form? react-redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

Currently I have an array that exists in the store, a dispatch a push action that will push an empty object into that array.

In a component, it will map over that array and render forms with the according formModel.

When I inspect the store with redux dev tools, all is okay and the react-redux-form is registered and exists.

But when typing into the form I get an error:
Uncaught Error: Could not find form for "dependants.3" in the store.

After this, all the existing react-redux-forms are broken and are no longer editable.

I was wondering if there is an official way to dynamically add a form with react-redux-form? I tried searching docs and issues, no luck.

Comment: When you render your form, are you giving it a unique name with the `form` prop? (As opposed to exporting with the `form` property in the config of `reduxForm()`)

Comment: @Tony The form prop is for Redux Form, I'm using react-redux-form

Comment: apologies, I missed that